# Upload file using $post jquery function

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, file-upload

```
 $(".btnSavePurpose").click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       var item=$(this);
       $.post("url", 
                         item.closest("form").serialize(), function(data){
           if(data.Status=="Success")
           {
             //Let's replace the form with messsage                
             alert("Updated Successfully");
           }    
           else
           {
              alert(data.ErrorMessage);
           }

       });   
    });
```

I want to post my form using ajax. I have used $post() jquery function. I am getting all  data without file which is uploaded. I have added enctype to form. I am getting Request.File["file"] null. How I can retrive uploaded file

```
<form method="post" id="profile-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <table>
     <tr>
        <td style="width: 25%">
         Profile Name<span class="Require">&nbsp;*</span>
         </td>
         <td style="width: 10%">
          :
         </td>
          <td style="width: 70%">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ProfileName, new { @class = "formTextBox" })
          </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td>
          My Ocupation<span class="Require">&nbsp;*</span>
       </td>
       <td>
       :
       </td>
       <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Ocupation, new { @class = "formTextBox" })
       </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>
         Upload New Profile Photo
      </td>
      <td>
         :
      </td>
      <td>
            <input type="file" name="file" id="file" runat="server" accept="gif|jpg|png|jpeg|bmp" />                                                       
      </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
 <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit" class="formButton" />
 </form>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload

Answer (score 0):

try this example
***html***

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="file" id="myFile" name="myFile" />
 <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnUpload" OnClick="btnUploadClick" Text="Upload" />
</form>
```

***.net***

```
 protected void btnUploadClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files["myFile"];

        //check file was submitted
        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            string fname = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(Path.Combine("~/App_Data/", fname)));
        }
    }
```

***how to write js take a look here*** [Using jQuery to send data from a multipart/form-data through ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7516381/using-jquery-to-send-data-from-a-multipart-form-data-through-ajax)

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid what you're trying to do is not this simple. You cannot read a file with JavaScript. You have no access to the file system whatsoever. This means that you cannot post a file with AJAX. (Well, it can be done with HTML5 - see: [How can I upload files asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery))

There's a lot of ways to go about the problem to solve it, something you can hammer together rather quickly on your own is to post the file in an iframe. I'd recommend using a jQuery plugins for this, for example http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/.

Comment: I am storing file in the database directly

Comment: Here's an article for that: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1757/File-Upload-with-ASP-NET#get